# running the python script in command line does not print any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I want to make a script in python and then run it from the command line. The script is called `test.py` and the command to run it is:

```
python3 test.py John Jackson
```

Here is the expected output:

```
John Jackson
```

And here is the python script I made:

```
class person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def get_first(self):
        return self.firstname

    def get_last(self):
        return self.lastname

import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('first')
    parser.add_argument('last')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    c1 = person(args.first, args.last)
    print(c1)
```

But the problem is when I run the script from the command line using the mentioned command, it returns nothing. Do you know how to fix it and get the expected output?

Comment: I fixed that but still no results.

Comment: Python does not automatically run a function called `main`.  Some other languages may do that, but not Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are calling your main function while running the script.

Add

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And override `__str__` function of the person class to print first name and last name while passing class as argument to `print`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

The whole code goes like this

```
import argparse

class person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def get_first(self):
        return self.firstname

    def get_last(self):
        return self.lastname

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('first')
    parser.add_argument('last')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    c1 = person(args.first, args.last)
    print(c1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

You defined your `main()` function but did not call it.

Add this at the end of your script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

See [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/2745495).

Then, `c1` is the `person` instance, which would print:

```
$ python3 test.py John Jackson
<__main__.person object at 0x104907ef0>
```

You need to call `get_first()` and `get_last()` to get the correct output:

```
print(c1.get_first(), c1.get_last())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is unnecessarily [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Features_and_philosophy), a much (***much***) simpler way to achieve this is to use the `argv` property of the `sys` module then separate the (string) argument using `split`, like this:

```
import sys

name = sys.argv[1].split(" ")

if len(name) != 2:
  raise ValueError("Invalid first and last name, try using \"John Jackson\" instead.")

[first_name, last_name] = name
print(first_name, last_name)
```

You don't even need to raise an error:

```
import sys

name = sys.argv[1].split(" ")

if len(name) == 2:
  [first_name, last_name] = name
  print(first_name, last_name)
```

Then when you run the script like this:

```
python3 filename.py "John Jackson"
```

You should get the following output:

```
John Jackson
```

Good luck.